# Case insensitive Restriction.IN

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I've googled a bit but found no decent solutions...

What i would like to achieve, source comes firts :)

```
 List<MyStuff> result =
 session.createCriteria(MyStuff.class)
 .add(Restrictions.in("name", templates)).list();
```

templates is a Collection, thing is, I would like to get all myStuffs, that have name column **matching-CASE-INSENSITIVELY** to any of templates.

Possible without looping and iliking for every element of templates?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this feature is not implemented in the Criteria API.
You must implement your own InExpression. See the answer in [Ignorecase for In-Criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542902/ignorecase-for-in-criterion)